# jQuery filter method usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

What's the use of below snippet ? I extracted it from jQuery API. I don't understand it:

```
$("div").filter( $("#unique") )
```

Please be kind enough to explain this to me.

Comment: Just because I don't know people have downgrade my question. WOW

Comment: Your downvotes are because you clearly didn't research this question before posting it here. jQuery has [very clear and well-written documentation available online](http://api.jquery.com), which should always be your starting point for questions like this.

Comment: The voting method here is rather strict, sometimes unfair. Learn to adapt.

Comment: by the way I read the documentation at the 1st place but I couldn't understand. That's why I post it here as a question hoping for an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is extracting the only one `div` with `id=unique`.

```
$('div').  // return all divs
   filter( $('#unique') ); // take the div with id=unique
```

So. this statement will return you the `div` with `id=unique`.

#### Note

This statement can also be written as `$('div#unique')` or just `$('#unique')`.

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` method enables you to filter out only specific elements from amongst a selection. Say you want to choose all `span`s whose text contains more than 3 characters. So you would do this:

```
$("span").filter(function() { return $(this).text().length > 3; }).click(...);
```

The function should check for some condition and return a `boolean`. if it sends `true` that element is kept in the selection, else discarded. So for your current question, it would